# How do I connect a Lenovo IdeaPad S6000 to Windows 7 (64-bit)

Tags: android, adb

Lonovo does not appear to provide any drivers for the ADB Interface and Google's USB Drivers do not support the Lenovo IdeaPad.  How do I get the ADB Interface installed?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You will first need the Device IDs of the IdeaPad.  You can find these in the Device Manager, by right clicking on "IdeaPad S6000" under "Other Devices".  Select the "Details" tab and choose the "Hardware Ids" Property.  In my case these were the two values (though searching for these steps online has led to many other slight variations):

```
USB\VID_17EF&PID_75E0&REV_0255&MI_01
USB\VID_17EF&PID_75E0&MI_01
```

Then using the Google USB Drivers found in the [Android-SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) (`andriod-sdk/extras/google/usb_driver`) look for the file `android_winusb.inf`.  There are two sections defined for device drivers, one (the first) for 32-bit operating systems (`[Google.NTx86]`) and one for 64-bit operating systems (`[Google.NTamd64]`).  You will see a series of Google Reference devices (Nexus One, Nexus Q etc.)  At the end of these devices add the following three lines:

```
;IdeaTab S6000
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_17EF&PID_75E0&REV_0255&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_17EF&PID_75E0&MI_01
```

Save and exit, then attempt to install the the Google OEM USB Driver.  With your Hardware Ids in place Windows 7 should recognized the driver and then the device.  I have tested this on my Windows 7 desktop and now Appcelerator Titanium and my Android Jelly Bean tablet are talking perfectly together :)  I hope this can help anyone else.

Comment: Jason, thanks for this solution. It worked for me. However, I got stuck on your last step where you said "attempt to install the Google OEM USB Driver". I wasn't sure what that meant. I thought it might mean to use the Android SDK Manager to reinstall the Extras>Google USB Driver. What it in fact meant was to return to the Windows Device Manager, go back to the Properties dialog box for the failed usb device, choose Update Driver, choose Browse, and then navigate to andriod-sdk/extras/google/usb_driver (if necessary).

Comment: So the file you edited (`android_winusb.inf`) is in the same folder as the rest of the driver files.  If you open up the device manager and locate the unknown device representing your tablet, you can follow [these instructions](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-install-hardware-or-device-drivers-manually-in-windows-vista/) and point the folder to the folder with the edited `.inf`.  I'd add more screenshots but I'm typing this on a mac at the moment. Good luck, I hope this helps :)

Comment: Yes, I was saying the same thing. I was just providing that information in case someone else got confused where I did.

Comment: Thanks for bring it up then. I'll add in the extra information :)

Comment: Also - if there's no "unknown device" try switching the storage type in "Settings"->"Storage"->"USB computer connection".

Comment: And this will not work on 64-bit windows unless you can sign the driver after editing the .inf file.

Comment: @Axarydax, maybe it's a security setting on your computer, the laptop I worked this out on was a 64-bit Windows 7 OS (here is a screen shot I just took to be sure: http://imgur.com/bR2j2Fg)

Comment: @JasonSperske Strange, Windows 8 x64 said to me that the certificate's digital signature no longer matches the file (because I changed the .inf file) - but I signed the driver and then it worked.

Comment: Glad you found a workaround, I haven't tried windows 8 yet (just switched to OSX and never looked back, except to capture this screen shot I guess :)

Comment: what about MAC? Any help?